# How to identify a column as a name column for an PCA with an excel file?

Tags: r

I'm steel a debutant on R and I would like to do an PCA.

Here is my dataset:

```
structure(list(Varietes.rep = c("EPS45_2", "EPS47_1", "EPS45_1", "OPM_2", "EPS41_2", "EPS46_1", "Belet_1", "EPS42_2", "BDA_2", "Osoro_1"), ASI = c(4, 6, 2, 0, 3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 2), DTSnum = c(19, 16, 18, 16, 20, 25, 22, 16, 23, 22), DTAnum = c(15, 10, 16, 16, 17, 20, 19, 14, 17, 20), Amplitude = c(9, 14, 9, 4, 7, 8, 11, 6, 10, 6), AUC = c(416.6667, 512.1622, 353.4483, 20.98765, 327.907, 288.6364, 400, 108.8608, 601.6393, 260.6557), Pourcentage.pieds.steriles.femelle = c(4, 2.27272727272727, 1.5625, 0, 5.8252427184466,7.69230769230769, 1.20481927710843, 1.0752688172043, 1.2987012987013, 2.66666666666667), Hauteur.moyenne = c(270.3676, 256.6753, 281.0508, 288.0988, 272.4674, 293.8163, 303.4189, 264.7375, 258.371, 294.4444), Hauteur.moyenne.soies =c(101.8154, 100.6533, 101.8947, 100.2716, 101.8372, 130.7391, 126.2361, 97.1125, 102.7705, 122.7097), Pourcentage.double.epis = c(29.4117647058824, 33.3333333333333, 41.1764705882353, 74.5098039215686, 15.6862745098039, 29.4117647058824, 47.0588235294118, 58.8235294117647, 27.4509803921569, 31.3725490196078)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My column name is "Varietes.rep" and I would like to precise that this variable is my individus, for my PCA.

How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The named column needs to be the rowname, so you need to convert the column to rownames first:

```
library(magrittr)
pca = dat %>%
    tibble::column_to_rownames("Varietes.rep") %>%
    prcomp()
```

```
Standard deviations (1, .., p=9):
[1] 1.740407e+02 1.940922e+01 1.244057e+01 4.747485e+00 2.481467e+00 1.197997e+00 3.621528e-01 1.236234e-01 9.236234e-16

Rotation (n x k) = (9 x 9):
                                            PC1          PC2          PC3         PC4          PC5          PC6         PC7         PC8           PC9
ASI                                -0.009441536 -0.004237640  0.023921657 -0.19086237 -0.052048523 -0.315610214  0.20076598  0.69780588  5.773503e-01
DTSnum                             -0.006867303  0.125533815  0.062339752 -0.13742720  0.558004323 -0.308139050 -0.23453973  0.40836369 -5.773503e-01
DTAnum                              0.002574233  0.129771455  0.038418095  0.05343516  0.610052846  0.007471164 -0.43530572 -0.28944219  5.773503e-01
Amplitude                          -0.013888223 -0.004206378 -0.058284888 -0.08600605 -0.513714294 -0.075437642 -0.83548049  0.14619983 -1.541798e-15
AUC                                -0.996727987  0.013670006 -0.075289266  0.01591253  0.008442632 -0.005448888  0.01329253 -0.01212881  1.000562e-16
Pourcentage.pieds.steriles.femelle -0.001913776  0.047541419  0.149077548 -0.08786674 -0.152057897 -0.855253847  0.08990259 -0.45291086  8.907345e-16
Hauteur.moyenne                     0.037010923  0.739041840 -0.244336259  0.59755584 -0.107680234 -0.097974355  0.04572905  0.11130594 -4.653036e-16
Hauteur.moyenne.soies              -0.002450546  0.624853368  0.002744968 -0.73347830 -0.078457457  0.203460007  0.07873022 -0.13343280  7.895899e-16
Pourcentage.double.epis             0.069412039 -0.168206275 -0.950298953 -0.17718858  0.094402269 -0.131187195  0.02483250 -0.07540691  1.981639e-16
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is your code for standard deviations and rotation? because i don't understand !

Comment: @Jean I was just printing the pca object by typing pca in the terminal and pressing enter.

Comment: @Jean No worries. On stackoverflow we upvote and accept answers so that other users know that the answer was useful. Please feel free to accept or upvote any of the answers provided here (or not if they didn’t help). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can set the `row.names` with the first column while removing the first column and apply the `prcomp`

```
prcomp(`row.names<-`(as.data.frame(df1[-1]), df1[[1]]))
```

-output

```
Standard deviations (1, .., p=9):
[1] 1.740407e+02 1.940922e+01 1.244057e+01 4.747485e+00 2.481467e+00 1.197997e+00 3.621528e-01 1.236234e-01 4.044832e-15

Rotation (n x k) = (9 x 9):
                                            PC1          PC2          PC3         PC4          PC5          PC6         PC7         PC8           PC9
ASI                                -0.009441536 -0.004237640  0.023921657 -0.19086237 -0.052048523 -0.315610214  0.20076598  0.69780588 -5.773503e-01
DTSnum                             -0.006867303  0.125533815  0.062339752 -0.13742720  0.558004323 -0.308139050 -0.23453973  0.40836369  5.773503e-01
DTAnum                              0.002574233  0.129771455  0.038418095  0.05343516  0.610052846  0.007471164 -0.43530572 -0.28944219 -5.773503e-01
Amplitude                          -0.013888223 -0.004206378 -0.058284888 -0.08600605 -0.513714294 -0.075437642 -0.83548049  0.14619983  2.371367e-15
AUC                                -0.996727987  0.013670006 -0.075289266  0.01591253  0.008442632 -0.005448888  0.01329253 -0.01212881  0.000000e+00
Pourcentage.pieds.steriles.femelle -0.001913776  0.047541419  0.149077548 -0.08786674 -0.152057897 -0.855253847  0.08990259 -0.45291086 -1.486224e-15
Hauteur.moyenne                     0.037010923  0.739041840 -0.244336259  0.59755584 -0.107680234 -0.097974355  0.04572905  0.11130594  1.144917e-16
Hauteur.moyenne.soies              -0.002450546  0.624853368  0.002744968 -0.73347830 -0.078457457  0.203460007  0.07873022 -0.13343280 -3.131176e-16
Pourcentage.double.epis             0.069412039 -0.168206275 -0.950298953 -0.17718858  0.094402269 -0.131187195  0.02483250 -0.07540691  3.469447e-17
```